# Error: Multiple elements with name 'car', with different types, appear in the model group

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to make schema for an XML that has two elements with the same name & content. Is there a way to make this possible while keeping the correct order of the elements?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vehicles>
    <car>honda</car>
    <train>amtrak</train>
    <car>honda</car>
</vehicles>
```

XSD (edited):

```
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="vehicles">
    <xs:complexType name="carType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="car" type="carType">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                    <xs:attribute name="newAttribute" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="train">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                    <xs:attribute name="newAttribute" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="car" type="carType">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                    <xs:attribute name="newAttribute" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

</xs:schema>

Comment: Use sequence : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_sequence.asp

Answer (score 0):

The "Element declarations consistent" rule says that if two sibling elements have the same name, then they must have the same type: specifically, they must all be references to the same globally-declared type. So change both occurrences to `<xs:element name="car" type="carType">` and declare `carType` as a top-level `<complexType name="carType">` definition.

Now I've noticed that your element declarations are all top-level, and you have no definition of the `vehicles` element. You need to fix that as well. But I suspect that's a cut-and-paste error, because the error message makes it clear that they're actually in a model group.

Comment: Good catch. I've edited the schema with the parts you've mentioned but the error is still there. Additionally, there is the error "Element 'car' has both a 'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child. Only one of these is allowed for an element."

Comment: Please don't change the question after it's been answered and then expect me to answer the new question. The whole thread becomes totally incoherent. If you have a new question, raise it on a new thread. The error message is pretty clear about what you did wrong - read my answer again, more carefully.